# Cycle through HTML pages or DIVs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have to display screen fulls of content on a monitor with graphs coming from our monitoring system at work. How do I loop through various sections of contents from either one page which has everything separated by DIVs or through multiple HTML files?

I would like to do this with jQuery, if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: what you have tried still now? Can you post your html part?

Comment: I was able to do this by using creating a window.onload function and using jQuery to fadeIn and fadeOut through the DIVs. This comment doesn't allow me to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Html:**

```
<div id="dv1/>
<div id="dv2"/>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#dv1').load('htmlpage1.htm');

$('#dv2').load('htmlpage2.htm');
```

You can fill content in your divs by using load function.

Answer (score 0):

the basic syntax is:

```
yourSelector.doSomething
```

yourSelector = a DOM selector to grab the divs you want. For intance, if your divs all have a class of `myDiv` you'd use $('.myDiv')

doSomething is, well, some event or function you want to set up or call.

As for 'looping through separate HTML pages' that's not really something you'd typically do client-side.